# Regression with Pooled data in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, panel-data

#### Context:

I have "pooled data" with time and cross section dimensions. 
It is unbalanced data without a full range of time observations for each cross section of observations. 
It is kind of like unbalanced panel data?

I wish to proceed with the limited number of observations without losing any data.

#### Questions:

- How can I get regression results (generalized least squares?) in SPSS with this kind of data?
- What should I pay attention to when evaluating the results?

Answer (score 2):

Mixed models are usually used to take account of the correlation structure likely with a model like this.  Look up Analyze>Mixed Models (MIXED) or the newer Mixed Models>Generalized Linear if you have the latest version.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to weight by duration of observation, perhaps by simple division, in essence turning data into an annualized rates. There will be issues relating to whether persons (or other units of analysis) have systematically higher or lower rates in the early period of observation or enrollment.